# Problema ao Incluir SDL no CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl

Estou baixando a SDL mingw deste [site](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). Eu descompactei o arquivo zipado e copiei essas pastas:

> bin, include, lib

E colei todas elas no caminho do CodeBlock

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW

Já configurei a parte do Linker Settings

> -Imingw32
>
> -ISDLmain
>
> -ISDL

Configurei a parte do Search Directories

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\SDL2

E quando vou fazer o teste com esse código console abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Me retorna este erro:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test3 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\..\..\..\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7)||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Não consigo saber onde está o problema, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Tenta substituir `-ISDLmain -ISDL` por `-ISDL2main -ISDL2`

Comment: Ainda continua dando o mesmo problema